# Почему getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag возвращает null после поворота экрана?

Tags: android, android-fragment, интерфейс, android-support-library

Я пытаюсь разработать приложение, которое содержит всего одну `Activity` и два `Fragments`. Каждый Fragment может вызывать метод интерфейса, реализуемый `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentRequest(final String fragmentTag) {

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              // симулируем работу с сетью
              Thread.sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);

                if(fragment == null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "fragment is null");
                else {
                    if(fragment instanceof OnFragmentResponse)
                        ((OnFragmentResponse) fragment).onFragmentResponse();
                }
              }
          });
      }
  }).start();

}
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что после поворота экрана (изменении конфигурации) после вызова `onFragmentRequest` приводит к тому, что `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)` возвращает `null`

Все фрагменты я заменяю и добавляю в бэк-стек, и после всего этого вызываю метод `commit`, а также `manager.executePendingTransactions()`, но и это не решает проблему

Логи до или без поворота экрана:

```
02-07 16:39:12.202 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: onFragmentRequest: fragmentTag = NewsFragment
02-07 16:39:12.203 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: getSupportFragmentManager.entryCount = 1
02-07 16:39:12.203 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/NewsFragment: onFragmentResponse success
```

Логи, когда был вызван `onFragmentRequest` и произошел поворот:

```
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: onFragmentRequest: fragmentTag = NewsFragment
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: getSupportFragmentManager.entryCount = 1
02-07 16:39:23.454 29750-29750/com.testfrag3 D/MainActivity: fragment is null
```

Comment: Видать код вызывается в уже "уничтоженной" активити и в ней ничего нет вот и Null. Попробуйте перенести эмуляцию работы с сетью в Singlton и из него в нужный момент вызывать метод актвити, ссылку на кою активити будет в синглтон передавать при start, а убирать при stop, например

Comment: Тоже думаю, что причина в том, что вызываю `getSupportFragmentManager` из уничтоженной активити, но тогда как-то в голове не укладывается: активити то уничтожена, а вот ее контекст - нет, и можно вызывать ее методы. Также думал, что `runOnUiThread` будет вызываться из новосозданной активити, но не тут то было)

Comment: Вариант из синглтоном мне нравится. Просто изначально не хотел ничего держать в фоне. Активити должна была выступать в роле контроллера. Сейчас думаю для этого сделать отдельный класс AsyncTask на основе retain-фрагмента, к которому и будут обращаться фрагменты и сама активити, когда нужно получить или отправить данные из сети.

Comment: Для тех, кто будет искать ответ на этот вопрос: https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-worker-fragments